# content security policy : images are not loading while adding style-src directive

Tags: javascript, html, css, cordova, content-security-policy

Here is my CSP for my mobile web application.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; img-src * 'self' data: *; style-src  'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
```

But when i add `style-src` (ie `style-src  'self' 'unsafe-inline';`)directive `img-src` directive is not applied  ie images are not loading.

if i remove `style-src` i got the following error

> Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following
>   Content Security Policy directive: "default-src *". Either the
>   'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash

Comment: are they images in the img tag or background images set in css?

Comment: Nop it's actually icon images

Comment: icon images? can you post an example?

Comment: Let me add the example on question

Comment: some of them look like this`<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin" ng-show="loading"></i>`

Comment: @jcesarmobile any idea???

Comment: yeah, that looks like it's using background css images to show the icons, so it's affected by the style-src instead of being affected by the img-src. Try adding `*` to the style-src

Comment: I added the following after img-src `style-src * 'unsafe-inline'` but the issue persists

Comment: also keep the `'self'`

Comment: added self but getting the same result here is the full tag `style-src * 'self' 'unsafe-inline';`